# Как написать функцию onDragEnd, чтобы работал dnd?

Tags: reactjs, drag-n-drop

Есть компонент Main, в котором еще 4 компонента, которые и должны менять места между собой. Сейчас компоненты перетягиваются, но не остаются на местах. Понимаю, что при изменении местоположения, у компонента должен меняться индекс.
Использую библиотеку react-beautiful-dnd.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import CardWeather from '../cardWeather/CardWeather';
import WeatherMap from '../cardWeatherMap/WeatherMap';
import Forecast from '../forecast/Forecast';
import WeatherGrapth from '../weatherGraph/WeatherGraph';
import './main.scss';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Main = () => {

  const [components, setComponents] = useState([{
    components: {
      'component-1': {id: 'comp-1'},
      'component-2': {id: 'comp-2'},
      'component-3': {id: 'comp-3'},
      'component-4': {id: 'comp-4'},
    }
  }
  ])

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    const { destination, source } = result
    console.log(result)
    if (!destination) {
      return
    }
    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return
    }
    
  }


    return (
<>
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}> 
      <Droppable droppableId="main">
        {
          (provided) => (
            <div className="main-container"
            ref={provided.innerRef} 
            {...provided.droppableProps}
            >
              <CardWeather />              
              <Forecast/>
              <WeatherGrapth/>
              <WeatherMap/>
              {provided.placeholder}
        </div>
          )
        }
      </Droppable>
        <div className="pr">weather app</div>
        </DragDropContext>
        </>
    )
}

export default Main;
```